# How can I allow user input from the beginning of the line in C# console app?

Tags: c#, input, user-input

I know I can use Console.ReadLine() to allow user input but it only allows user input from where the cursor is positioned, I want a way to be able to allow user input from the beginning of the line (over the whole line) and not only from where the cursor is positioned. for example:

```
for (int i = 1;i <= 5;i++) Console.Write(i+" ");
string x = Console.ReadLine();
```

This would give the following output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 _
```

Where '_' refers to the cursor, this way, the user will be able to write only from the cursor position - he cannot use backspace to delete the former characters too. So how can I allow user input over the whole line while the cursor is not at the beginning of the line?

Comment: The C# shell simply isn't really designed to do this out of the box.  Pretty sure you're going to just have to read in the console input one key at a time, and handle moving the cursor when the user presses an arrow key, backspace key, etc. yourself.  You're probably best simply adjusting your UI; either use a UI that's more suitable to a console application, or use a non-console UI that's really designed for a more intricate user interaction.

Comment: @Servy Reading a key at a time is the closest solution of course, but it would be more complex to handle storing these values in an array or in a list because that is not going to behave like a simple do-it-all `Console.ReadLine()` that begins to process values after the user finishes entering them so it sees the whole line and not as far as a character from the current cursor position.

Comment: I mean if you're going to do that you'd want to write your own method that does all of the needed work and returned a string when it was done, so that the caller can just call that method and get a string.  Writing such a method would indeed take a lot of work though.  That's why I said you'd should avoid needing to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is ready to go example with custom input handling.
Of cource this is require some tweaks towards performance but it should give you and idea where to begin.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<char> outputString = new List<char>();
        outputString = "test".ToCharArray().ToList();
        //If there is something in outputString write it to buffer and set cursor position
        if (outputString.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.Write(outputString.Select(x => x.ToString()).Aggregate((x, y) => x + y));
        }

        while (true)
        {
            //This will read user input but it will not print it to the console window 
            var key = Console.ReadKey(true);
            //Allow user maniputate cursor to the right
            //Here you can add another condition to prevent line overflow or some constrains
            //if(Console.CursorLeft < 30)
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow && Console.CursorLeft < outputString.Count)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft + 1, Console.CursorTop);
            }
            else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow && Console.CursorLeft > 0)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft - 1, Console.CursorTop);
            }
            //Here you should add all keys that your input should take, special characters are ok above ASCII number 32 which is space
            else if (key.KeyChar >= 48 && key.KeyChar <= 57 || //Read numbers
                key.KeyChar >= 64 && key.KeyChar <= 90 || //Read capital letters
                key.KeyChar >= 97 && key.KeyChar <= 122 || //Read lower letters
                key.Key == ConsoleKey.Spacebar)
            {
                Console.Write(key.KeyChar);
                if(Console.CursorLeft > outputString.Count)
                {
                    outputString.Add(' ');
                }
                outputString[Console.CursorLeft - 1] = key.KeyChar;
            }
            //This will remove character
            else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && Console.CursorLeft > 1)
            {
                ClearCurrentConsoleLine();
                outputString.RemoveAt(Console.CursorLeft - 1);
                var currentLeft = Console.CursorLeft;
                Console.CursorLeft = 0;
                Console.Write(outputString.Select(x => x.ToString()).Aggregate((x,y) => x + y));
                Console.CursorLeft = currentLeft - 1;
            }
            //This ends input loop
            //You can add more keys to break current loop with OR condition
            else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        //Display result and wait for any key
        Console.WriteLine(outputString.Select(x => x.ToString()).Aggregate((x, y) => x + y));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    //Clears current console line and sets cursor at where it was before
    public static void ClearCurrentConsoleLine()
    {
        int currentLineCursorTop = Console.CursorTop;
        int currentLineCursorLeft = Console.CursorLeft;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);
        Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
        Console.SetCursorPosition(currentLineCursorLeft, currentLineCursorTop);
    }
```

Comment: Great! that perfectly handled the user input in this case, but after pressing Enter is there a way to read the whole line to start processing what the user entered or even at the beginning of the input process?just like what `Console.ReadLine()` does, reads the whole line to begin processing it in the next operation after storing it in a string.

Comment: Whole data is in outputString variable which is List of chars. To convert it to plain string you need to aggregate an array like I do before every writeline method.

Comment: Some things that this doesn't support: characters in other languages (of particular note is surrogate pairs), home/end, pasting from the clipboard, punctuation, and hitting the end of the console's horizontal buffer.  I'm sure there is more, but that's just off the top of my head.

Comment: This is just a beginning, an idea, that requires further improvements, where you should add all of those features, but they are easy to add. Also if I'm not mistaken, C# Console supports only ASCII anyway. @Servy Welcome to StackOverflow where we don't write code for others, but point them in right directions :)

Comment: @TomaszJuszczak Many of those features are in fact going to be quite difficult to add.  As for what SO is as a site, it's a site where we provide quality answers to quality questions.  It's not a place where people provide half answers that don't really solve the problem.  The design of the site is that questions are limited in scope to those that can be answered quickly and succinctly without requiring an answer that involves writing an involved feature from scratch.

Comment: @Servy, of course, this is not going to do the same function of ReadLine(), there are also when you use left arrow and space it would write over the element and would not shift it like Console.ReadLine()

Comment: @TomaszJuszczak Yes, you provided an idea that has to be developed, you did what Servy stated in a previous comment

Answer (score -1):

You could use `Console.CursorLeft = 0;` for this. The advantage in comparison to `Console.SetCursorPosition` is, that you don't have to evaluate the y-coordinate, so that the cursor stays in the current line.

I want to make an example for this (in both cases we want the cursor to go to the beginning of the line):

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop); //With SetCursorPosition
Console.CursorLeft = 0; //With CursorLeft
```

However, I don't think there's an elegant way of letting the user delete the chars written by the program. You could still constantly check wether the user presses Backshift and then delete the last character and move the cursor back, while you'd have to check that asynchronously what wouldn't result in a nice solution.

Comment: But the OP *doesn't* want to move the cursor.  They want the cursor to stay right where it is, but just allow the user to move it themselves further to the left of where it starts.

Comment: @Servy stay calm, I'm actually in the progress of editing this answer.

Comment: If you haven't finished writing your answer, then you shouldn't post it.  Only post your answer once you feel it's ready to be evaluated.  That said, your edit has done nothing to address it's problems; the answer in no way answers the question.

Comment: Actually I'm quite sure that my answer fitted to the question, before an edit was made to the question.

Comment: @MetaColon Thanks for answering but as Servy said, I don't want to move the cursor, I want it to stay where it is but allow user input from that point and before it.